# Is there free WFS 2.0 client?

Tags: wfs, ogc, free-software

I have the task to provide my point observations data in the "WFS 2.0" (Web Feature Service 2.0) standard format.

Are there any free, easy-to-use, desktop GIS clients or online viewers for showing and querying my WFS 2.0 layers?

I have only found the "[QGIS WFS 2.0 Client plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/wfsclient/)"

Do any other popular free GIS viewers (Kosmo, MapWindow, ArcGIS explorer..) have support for showing and querying WFS 2.0 web feature service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The QGIS client plugin is a good one - I was able to access the features of WFS without issue.

[ArcGIS has an interoperability connections](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00370000000p000000) feature that must be enabled by a user with  administrator access first however I didn't try to get this working as the license is 2.5K and I don't have that license

OpenLayers supports WFS as does GRASS - [I found that info here](http://gdsc.nlr.nl/gdsc/en/information/ogc/wfs/client_software)

EDIT: additionally you can access your WFS from your browser as XML-ish data by following [this arcGIS tutorial](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000004rz000000)

Answer (score 3):

> QGIS 2.16 brings an overhaul of the WFS provider, including
>
> - WFS 1.1 and 2.0 support

Source: http://qgis.org/pl/site/forusers/visualchangelog216/index.html#id96

Answer (score 0):

spatialite_gui: https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=WFS

Supporting:

- WFS 1.0.0, 1.1.0 and 2.0.0 seemingly.